# aes-ni enabled but no kernel support?

Tags: centos

Tools like cpuid and `cat /proc/cpuinfo` can confirm that aes instructions are available right? But then I check `/proc/crypto` and do not see AES. I am running CentOS 6. Am I correct in my understanding that without the kernel module for aes loaded, I cannot take advantage of AES-NI instructions?

Would a tool like `modprobe` load the appropriate kernel module? (unfortunately I do not have administrator rights)

I am running a test program that uses AES-NI, and the performance an order of magnitude lower than expected.

I am also curious, with AES-NI disabled, what instructions is the cpu running instead? "Software emulation"?

EDIT: I see the following when i run modinfo

```
$ /sbin/modinfo aesni_intel
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/aesni-intel.ko
alias:          aes
license:        GPL
description:    Rijndael (AES) Cipher Algorithm, Intel AES-NI instructions optimized
srcversion:     E6C037FA50922CF84440A82
depends:        glue_helper,aes-x86_64,lrw,cryptd,aes_generic,ablk_helper
vermagic:       2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

EDIT2: Is the above the right module for AMD processors as well?

Comment: AES-NI support must be present before you open the encryption. Loading it afterwards won't make already open containers use it.

Comment: Those are usually implemented directly rather than going through the kernel's crypto interface

Comment: The performance seems to suggest that the hardware features aren't being used. I see in the source code that functions like `_mm_aeskeygenassist_si128` get called. What would it look like to go through the kernel interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/proc/crypto` lists algorithms that are available when the kernel itself performs cryptographic operations, for example for network protocols like IPsec and for disk encryption. This file does not convey information about what userland programs can do.

The `aesni_intel` module contains code that implements AES using the Intel AES-NI accelerator. It is needed to use AES-NI when kernel code needs to run AES.

As far as I know, using the AES-NI accelerator does not require any kernel code. A program only needs to issue the `AESxxx` CPU instructions. If the processor does not have AES-NI, the program will trigger an invalid instruction processor exception, which is translated as a SIGILL signal. It would be possible for the kernel to handle the exception by emulating the behavior of the missing instruction, but to my knowledge Linux does not do this for the AES-NI instructions.

The AES-NI instruction is compatible on Intel and AMD processors.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining it. I'm still not sure why the perf isn't there, but there are a few alternatives available to me that are adequate